# How does embedly.js resize image and?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, embedly

I follow the `mbedly-jquery` guide from [here](https://github.com/embedly/embedly-jquery)

It seems that I can't resize image by using

```
$.embedly.defaults.key = 'Your Embedly Key';
$.embedly.defaults.query = {width: 300};
```

The results is like this 
[image]

Here is my html `<body>`

```
<a class="embedly-card" data-card-theme="dark" href="https://github.com/embedly/embedly-jquery"></a>
<a class="embedly-card" data-card-theme="dark" href="http://rubyonrails.org/"></a>
<a class="embedly-card" data-card-theme="dark" href="https://www.facebook.com/"></a>
```

Here is my **jquery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
$.embedly.defaults.key = 'my key';
$.embedly.defaults.query = {width: 150};
$('a').embedly();
});
</script>
```